# two data is not storing in database through json

Tags: json

i am submitting detail through json that are name ,email,dob,date,time,mobile all the data is stored only two feilds are not stored in database that are date and time what to do

@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

```
        try{
            String urlParameters =
                    "name=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")+
                            "&email="+URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")+
                            "&dob="+URLEncoder.encode(dob, "UTF-8")+
                           "&mob="+URLEncoder.encode(mob, "UTF-8")+
                            "&stylename="+URLEncoder.encode(style, "UTF-8")+
                            "&refralname="+URLEncoder.encode(refralname, "UTF-8")+
                            "&apdate"+URLEncoder.encode(apdate, "UTF-8")+
                            "&aptime"+URLEncoder.encode(aptime, "UTF-8");
            result = Utilities.postParamsAndfindJSON("http://avninfosoft.com/agouwebs/register.php", urlParameters);

            Log.d("success", "" + result);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

.phpname=sadddd&email=narsimha.bansode%40gmail.com&dob=2017-5-4&mob=288888888888&stylename=marleytwist&refralname=sam&apdate2017-5-19&aptime2%3A30PM

Comment: which database? mysql?

Comment: Can you edit the title to: Date and Time field is not storing in database through json